# Using Corba string_dup versus using pointer to const

Tags: corba

There is something I don't get, please enlighten me.

Is there a difference between the following (client side code)?
1) blah = (const char *)"dummy";
2) blah = CORBA::string_dup("dummy");

... just googling a bit I see string_dup() returns a char * so the 2 may be equivalent.
I was thinking 2) does 2 deep copies and not 1.

I'm firing the question anyway now, please briefly confirm.

Thanks!

Comment: This was Orbix Corba impl (C++).

Answer (score 8):

```
const char* blah = "dummy";
```

The C++ compiler generates a constant array of characters, null-terminated, somewhere in a data section of your executable. `blah` gets a pointer to it.

```
char* blah = CORBA::string_dup("dummy");
```

The function `string_dup()` is called with an argument that is a pointer to that constant array of characters. `string_dup()` then allocates memory from the free store and copies the string data into the free-store-allocated memory. The pointer to the free-store memory is returned to the caller. It is the caller's job to dispose of the memory when finished with `CORBA::string_free()`. Technically the ORB implementation is allowed to use some special free-store, but most likely it is just using the standard heap / free-store that the rest of your application is using.

It is often much better to do this:

```
CORBA::String_var s = CORBA::string_dup("dummy");
```

The `String_var`'s destructor will automatically call `string_free()` when `s` goes out of scope.

Comment: Will destructor of `CORBA::String_out` automatically call `string_free` ?